# Algebraic integers as lattices and their corresponding tori

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, integer-lattices

It is known that, given a number field $K$ with degree $n$, one can embed the corresponding algebraic integers $O_K$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a lattice $\Lambda_K$. From here on, one can construct the torus $\mathbf{T}_K := \mathbb{R}^n/\Lambda_K$.

My question: are there any results relating $K$ and $\mathbf{T}_K$? In particular, I'm looking for results that are not (obviously) deduced from considering $\Lambda_K$ only.

Comment: This is used to prove finiteness of ideal class groups of number fields via the Minkowski bound. The covolume of that lattice (essentially the discriminant of the number field, up to sign) plays a role in the proof.

Comment: But isn't this a property that is clear from the lattice picture alone already? I am not familiar with the proof of the Minkowski bound, but does it require or become more clear using the torus instead of the lattice?

Comment: I mentioned the covolume of the lattice is used, which is the volume of the torus. You could phrase things without the torus, but the idea of there being an exact sequence $0 \to \Lambda_K \to \mathbf R^n \to T_K \to 0$ is conceptually clarifying. Look to Tate’s thesis if you want a more essential use of the torus, as its compactness is related to the compactness of the adele class group of $K$.